# Android webView no funciona solo al cargar URL

Tags: android-studio, webview-android

Tengo un problema, mi aplicación no carga la URL https://www.apeseg.org.pe/consultas-soat/

el problema es q si me salgo de la aplicación y cargo la misma URL desde el navegador del teléfono, esta url si funciona.

Por esto creo que no es un error de la red, sino algún error dentro de la aplicación.

mi código es este:

```
    String urlSOAT = "https://www.apeseg.org.pe/consultas-soat/";
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_visualizador);

        webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);   

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
              @Override
              public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                  super.onPageFinished(view, url);
              }
        webView.loadUrl(urlSOAT);
    });
    }
```

en el manifiest tengo:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

podrian ayudarme a solucionar el error porfa.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Debes realizar la carga de la url fuera de la definición del `WebViewClient`:

```
webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
    //* incorrecto webView.loadUrl(urlSOAT); 
});

webView.loadUrl(urlSOAT);
```

de esta forma se cargaría sin problema la url:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.apeseg.org.pe/consultas-soat/");

IGUAL NO ME CARGA PARECE SER UN ERROR DE SSL, COMO LOGRASTE CARGARLA?

Comment: No es error SSL de hecho es lo primero que verifique, debes cargar la URL iniciando con https:// es importante definir el protocolo.

Comment: Aegura que se cargue la url de esta forma: webView.loadUrl("https://www.apeseg.org.pe/consultas-soat/");

Comment: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("https:/ /www.apeseg.org.pe/consultas-soat/");

Sigo con el error por favor me podría decir en que estoy fallando.

Comment: He logrado hacerlo carga con handler.proceed();, pero no es lo correcto

Comment: handler.proceed(); se usa cuando no tiene tu página un certificado de seguridad, o estas usando http:// pero tu página debe cargar sin problema usando  "https:/ /www.apeseg.org.pe/consultas-soat/

Comment: Segui los pasos que me dijiste, he probado en un nuevo proyecto pero igual, me abre todas las páginas menos la indicada urlSOAT

Comment: que versión de android tiene tu dispositivo y como esta configurado tu build.gradle?

Comment: Android Studio 3.6.1, Emulador Nexus 5X API 29 x86
Tengo que configurar algo en el build.gradle?
En el onReceivedSslError me resuelve este error SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED "The certificate authority is not trusted." Por eso mi confusión al ver la pantalla que me envias que te carga normal.